# Container name changes after system restart

Tags: containers, systemd, podman

I am starting and stopping container using systemd unit file service as.

Taking container name as `hello`

`podman ps` shows `hello` in output

1. Auto generate unit file for hello

`podman generate systemd --new --files --name hello`

2. The unit file contains

> ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f %t/%n.ctr-id
>
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id --sdnotify=conmon
> --cgroups=no-conmon -d --hostname=first containerID
>
> ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman rm -f --ignore --cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id
>
> ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop --ignore --cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id

3. When I reboot system and check

   `systemctl status container-hello`

   I get status as `Active: running`
4. But if I run `podman ps -a` , I get to see `hello` as `inactive` as well as another container added say `hello2` as `running`.
5. `hello2` is associated with the unit file created in step 1 and `hello` is not.

I have used --hostname as suggested but I cannot see container with that name when checked with podman ps pr podman ps -a

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html:
*Podman generates a UUID for each container, and if a name is not assigned to the container with --name then it will generate a random string name. The name is useful any place you need to identify a container. This works for both background and foreground containers.*

So you may want to edit your unit file to contain

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run ... --name hello
```

If that fixes the problem but the way you generate the unit should cover the name, maybe it is worth filing a bug for podman.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. I added `--name` parameter in the `ExecStart` label inside unit file as:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id --sdnotify=conmon --cgroups=no-conmon -d --name=container_name ID`

2. When podman auto generates unit file, it makes sure that once the container is stopped, it should be removed by,

`ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman rm -f --ignore --cidfile=%t/%n.ctr-id`

I erased this line from the unit file.

Results:

1. I can start /stop/re start container now without the container getting removed.
2. When I restart my system (reboot), the container name remains same as it was before reboot. (name given in --name paramter)
3. Container auto restarts with same name everytime.